# Editable combobox for bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, combobox

Im trying to create a editable combobox using the below code and it works fine.
The only problem is the caret symbol is displaying on the left instead of right.

```
<div class="input-append btn-group">
                            <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButton" size="16" type="text" value="Error Duration">
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>Edit</li>
                                <li>Delete</li>
                                <li>Ban</li>
                            </ul>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three solutions:

1 (recommended):

Remove `btn-group` class (this class causes the problem, because every `.btn` inside `btn-group` block is floated to the left and your input isn't floated).

2:

Add `pull-right` class to your anchor.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
  <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
```

3:

```
input {
  float: left;
}
```